# __builtin__.iterator does not exist?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

Consider:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  2 2012, 16:55:39) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import __builtin__
>>> type(iter('123'))
<type 'iterator'>
>>> type(iter('123')).__class__
<type 'type'>
>>> type(iter('123')).__name__
'iterator'
>>> type(iter('123')).__module__
'__builtin__'
>>> __builtin__.iterator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'iterator'
>>> dir(__builtin__)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
>>>
```

Is it expected that `__builtin__.iterator` doesn't really exist? Is there an appropriate way to obtain a reference to that class without creating a nonce-instance with `iter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all internal object types are listed in the `__builtin__` structure, no.

You won't find the method type there either, nor the generator type, or many others. Only names that you'd actually use in your Python code are listed in that namespace.

Some such types are listed in the [`types` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html), but the iterator type isn't, because, as the [source states](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/241f9aa9fb89/Lib/types.py#l7):

```
# Iterators in Python aren't a matter of type but of protocol.  A large
# and changing number of builtin types implement *some* flavor of
# iterator.  Don't check the type!  Use hasattr to check for both
# "__iter__" and "next" attributes instead.
```

If you wanted to test if something is an iterator, use the [`Iterator` ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) instead:

```
import collections

if isinstance(something, collections.Iterator):
```

If you have some obscure need to get the `iterator` type as returned for strings, you can use `type()` on it:

```
>>> type(iter('123'))
<type 'iterator'>
```

and store that; that's how the `types` module produces many of its references.

However, know that that type is not universal:

```
>>> iterator = type(iter(''))
>>> isinstance(iter([]), iterator)
False
>>> iter([])
<listiterator object at 0x108e72d50>
>>> isinstance(reversed([]), iterator)
False
>>> reversed([])
<listreverseiterator object at 0x108e72d50>
```

yet testing with the ABC does recognise them all:

```
>>> from collections import Iterator
>>> isinstance(iter([]), Iterator)
True
>>> isinstance(iter(reversed([])), Iterator)
True
>>> isinstance(iter(''), Iterator)
True
```

If you need to create an iterator, then either produce a sequence and return the result of `iter()` on that, or produce an iterator type yourself. The latter is easy enough, either use a generator expression, use a generator function for `__iter__` or give your type a `__next__` method that produces an item each time it is called (and have `__iter__` return `self`).

Comment: Specifically, I'm adding support for `__reduce__` to jsonpickle, and tangling with the PEP307 requirement that __reduce__ return iterators for its last two items. Turns out that the builtin iterators aren't picklable using their own `__reduce__`, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Marcin: anything with a `__iter__` method and a `__next__` method is an iterator, no need to re-use a specific type.

Answer (score -1):

Worse than that, it is a type that is not immediately a class.

```
>>> type(iter(range(5)))
<type 'listiterator'>
```

When you ask a (new-style) class instance for its type it says it is a class.

```
>>> class X(object): pass
...
>>> type(X())
<class '__main__.X'>
```

(And why would they implement new functionality with an old-style class?)

Given that, if you got a hold of it what would you do with it?

OK, so you can get it, and if you poke around, there is a class in there somewhere

```
>>> it = iter(range(5)).__class__
```

But you can't inherit from it

```
>>> class it2(it): pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'listiterator' is not an acceptable base type
```

And monkey-patching it seems outright dastardly.  I hope something would stop you.

You also can't instantiate it directly:

```
>>> x = it()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'listiterator' instances
```

So isn't it better for it to just pretend not to exist, rather than showing up and apologizing for all the normal things it cannot do?

The same goes for things like **function**, **int**, **double**, **str**, etc.   Most of those at least let you instantiate them, but they are not really classes, and so going much farther is spooky.

Comment: You're confused between instances and types.

Comment: No, I am not.  What makes you think so?  I am getting the classes of the instances via type() or by referencing the `__class__` member.  There is no confusion.

Comment: No, you're right. Your confusion is about the difference between user-defined new-style classes, builtin classes, and classic classes. Just because the repr of a class does not feature the word "class" or it can't be used as a baseclass does not mean it isn't a class.

Comment: Not every type is a class: The docs say "Class objects support two kinds of operations: attribute references and instantiation."  So this is not a class.  It requires an outside function to instantiate itself.  You cannot create one from the class itself, you have to directly call the **type** function.  There is no base class here because the "class" of iterator objects is defined by its interface and there is no need to have a Python **class** for it.

Comment: There are a number of separate kinds of iterator objects in the standard implementation, at least in 2.7.6.  They cannot be instantiated and they do not share a base class above 'object'.  That makes them useless enough that it would be misleading to let people even see them.  That is the point.  For you to go looking for this nonexistent object shows that it is you, and not me, that is confused.

Comment: THEY exist, there are separate ones for dicts and lists and sets...  There is no place you could reasonably hook to affect all iterators.  They just used to all call themselves the same thing, while being different objects, and now they don't.

Comment: Who's talking about a hook to affect all iterators?

Comment: There is basically no other use for having this class, but to monkey-patch it.  So I assumed that was your goal.  Anything else you need to do can be done from the instances.  That is kind of why things like this stay hidden.  Actions on them would not accomplish what the might if this were an ordinary class.

Comment: Wrong again. Just because you can't think of it off the top of your head doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Stop being a jerk.  You asked why this object is not accessible. This is why.  You called it a class, the docs say it is not a class.  Then you accused me of being confused about one thing, then another.  This is a lot of dancing just to appear to be what you are not.

Comment: Just because I misidentified the incorrect assumption underlying your answer doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: We differ on a definition.  But you do not see me as a potential peer, you presume to tell me that i am confused.  You are being a jerk

Comment: A apologize for assuming I understood your goal.  But it is evidently more important to establish that the standards for being a class i cited from the docs are not proper than to clarify what that goal actually was.

Comment: No, identifying mistakes in your answer does not qualify me as "a jerk". It is the explanation for why I downvoted this answer. Both are normal and expected behaviours on this site. If you don't want people to tell you you're wrong post on your own blog with comments disabled.

Comment: Yeah, but I am still not wrong.  Something you cannot instantiate is not a class, it is only a type.  I have quoted the reason for saying so.  You have not responded to this clarification, just complained.

Comment: Your reference to "the documentation" comes from the tutorial. It's not actually a part of the standard terminology.

Comment: No specific behavior makes you a jerk.  The overweening sense of your own superiority evidenced by the way you are doing it is what makes you a jerk.