# Installing modules without pip in python script

Tags: python, pip, installation, testcomplete

I'm using AnyTree in an independent environment where there is no pip (testcomplete).

I started by moving the anytree folders to the required folders, and started getting import error for six. I downloaded six and placed it in as well, and now I get:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'iterator'
```

In case anyone is interested - this is the code for doing this without pip:

```
from os import sys


sys.path.insert(0, "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\Extensions\Python\Python34\Lib\site-packages")

import six
import anytree

udo = anytree.Node("Udo")
print(udo)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Google only returned this result: [__builtin__.iterator does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612946)

The only two options I can think of are - moving the folders physically (tried but given the error above) or installing through a script:

It doesn't seem to work either (on 2.7 and I tried an updated script on 3.6 but neither work).

```
import sys
import os
import site 
from importlib import reload

try:
   import pip
except ImportError:
   print "installing pip"
   cmd = "sudo easy_install pip"
   os.system(cmd)
   reload(site)

try: 
   import requests
except ImportError:
   print "no lib requests"
   import pip
   cmd = "sudo pip install requests"
   print "Requests package is missing\nPlease enter root password to install required package"
   os.system(cmd)
   reload(site)
```

Comment: Are you unable to use `sudo apt install python-pip`?

Comment: @CalebH. looks like it's windows.

Comment: @CalebH. This is windows and even still, I'm not allowed into the python terminal to execute pip or anything like that (the TestComplete IDE doesn't allow that)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something similar before and you are on the right track. Instead of

```
cmd = "sudo easy_install pip"
```

you need to try

```
cmd = "get-pip.py"
```

and have it point to the file you can download here https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py.

Also, you can run pip from the command line in windows, no need to be in a python terminal. Like So:

```
pip install requests
```